# Get HTML content of remote page with JS

Tags: javascript, html, post, get, cross-domain

How to **pull HTML content from remote website**--the output of a remote PHP script--to be displayed by a .html file without running a Web Server and **using pure JS** (or Ajax if vanillaJS would be too complex).

> Can't include https://quarantine.country/coronavirus/cases/usa/ output to the covid app (no apache, html only) and jQuery too big(!)?

We need this output:

```html
<html><head></head><body>In the US we have 79082 reported cases with 76075 still active. 1864 recovered and 1143 casualties. The death ratio in the US is 0.01 at the moment, 0.02 is recovering. Last update at 2020/03/26.
In the same time, we have 520755 total cases worldwide, with 23581 deaths and 122690 recovered, a 0.05/0.24 ratio.
</body></html>
```

*loading and including the html output of the remote script (index.php) with JS should do the trick. A simple solution would help a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Both are ok, to get the plain text or the full HTML output as-is. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your web server needs to return the HTTP header

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, you can learn more about this here: [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to allow all websites to access your web server. Then, you can use XMLHttpRequest:

```
function onReceive() {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.addEventListener("load", onReceive);
req.open("GET", "https://quarantine.country/coronavirus/cases/usa/");
req.send();
```

Edit: If you do not control the `quarantine.country` website, this is not possible without their collaboration or a web server of your own.

Comment: thanks a lot, especially the "CORS Edit:" missed that relevant part, makes complete sense